# Kendo UI menu Action and Controller produce error on ISP provider like DiscountASP.NET. Must use URL

Tags: kendo-ui

I create a Kendo UI for MVC Web Application project and it runs find on localhost. When deploying this as a web application to a subdirectory of my domain on either DiscountASP.NET or WinHost, I receive an error:

> The relative virtual path '~4/' is not allowed here.

```
Line 21:            </div>
Line 22: 
Line 23:            @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
Line 24:                    .Name("menu")
Line 25:                    .Items(menu => {
```

Somehow I was able to get the proper deployment done through an FTP deployment from Visual Studio 2012 at work. But from home it still does not work. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Web Deploy  and have properly stated the addresses for the web application. I searched within IIS 8 for some kind of a setting but cannot find one.

These two internet host providers have "virtual" web sites I guess though I am not familiar with how that works. I think it might be related.

The solution to this above for now is to change from the default Telerik provided code:

```
            @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name("menu")
                .Items(menu => {
                    menu.Add().Text("Home").Action("Index", "Home");
                    menu.Add().Text("About").Action("About", "Home");
                }))
```

To this:

```
            @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name("menu")
                .Items(menu => {
                    menu.Add().Text("Home").Url("~/Home/Index");
                    menu.Add().Text("About").Url("~/Home/About");
                }))
```

If there is a way I can get back to the Controller and Action method of using Telerik's Kendo UI Menu in the MVC wrapper, I would appreciate knowing that. I have submitted a help ticket on the Host provider to see what I might do in the deployment stages but otherwise I am not sure what to do next.

Edit: The Internet Host Provider indicated that I need to contact the vendor (Telerik Kendo UI) to check why the wrapper is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
 menu.Add().Url(Url.Action("About", "Home")).Text("About");
```